# Iterate over a JSON Object in Angular 2

Tags: angular

I am a newbie in angular 2 and trying to iterate over a JSON object. the JSON response is :

```
{  
   "number":3,
   "message":"success",
   "people":[  
      {  
         "name":"Peggy Whitson",
         "craft":"ISS"
      },
      {  
         "name":"Fyodor Yurchikhin",
         "craft":"ISS"
      },
      {  
         "name":"Jack Fischer",
         "craft":"ISS"
      }
   ]
}
```

MY service code/ http get request:

```
@Injectable()

export class AstronautsHttpService{
    constructor(private _http: Http) {}

    getAstronauts(){
       // return this._http.get('http://date.jsontest.com/')
        return this._http.get('http://api.open-notify.org/astros.json')
        .map((res:Response) => res.json());
    }
}
```

the display component is :

```
export class DisplayComponent{

    private number:any;
    private message:any;
    private people:any
    constructor(private AstronautService:AstronautsHttpService) {}

    ngOnInit(){
        this.number = this.AstronautService.getAstronauts()
        .subscribe( Q => this.number = Q.number);
        this.number = this.AstronautService.getAstronauts()
        .subscribe( Q => this.message= Q.message);
        this.message = this.AstronautService.getAstronauts()
        .subscribe( data => {
          this.people = data.people;
          this.people.forEach(m => console.log(m.name))
          this.people.forEach(m => console.log(m.craft));
        });
    }
}
```

I have managed to print the number and message but when it comes to iterate over people it is not working.

I would really appreciate any advice /help.

Comment: What do you mean by not working? Getting errors?

Comment: Try put console.log(m['name']) and what show it

Comment: thank you alehn 96

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why are you doing make three service calling get single Json.

you can try like this.

```
     private people:any[]

        ngOnInit(){
                this.message = this.AstronautService.getAstronauts()
                .subscribe( data => {
                   this.number = data.number;
                  this.message= data.message;
                  this.people = data.people;
                  this.people.forEach(m => {
                   console.log(m.name,m.craft);})

                });
            }
```

Comment: Thank you Jonnysai for the help. What I forgot to mention was that I would  like to display all the information in the view section(html ) of the component. i have made the following amendments.......>private people:any[];...................> ngOnInit(){
        this.AstronautService.getAstronauts()
        .subscribe(
         data => {
            this.jsonResponse = JSON.stringify(data);
            this.number = data.number;
            this.message = data.message;
            this.people = data.people;
         }   and the html file of the component..........>

Comment: and the html component:........><p class="h3"> <strong>JSON RESPONSE:</strong> {{jsonResponse}}</p>
<p class="h3"> <strong>Number::</strong> {{number}}</p>
<p class="h3"> <strong>Message::</strong> {{message}}</p>
<div *ngFor="let Astronauts of people">
    <p class="h3"><strong> AstronautsName:: </strong>{{Astronauts.name}} <br/><strong> CraftName ::</strong> {{Astronauts.craft}}</p>
</div>

Answer (score 0):

Try map method to iterate., like this:

```
.subscribe( 
    (data) => {
      this.people = data.people;
      this.people.map((person) => {
         console.log(person.name, person.craft);
      })
    });
```

Comment: Thank you Mani S for the help.